# Foursquare push notification API

Tags: api, push-notification, real-time, foursquare

I would like to get the checkins of the users of my app by using the push notification. I am new to the foursquare API. I would be thankful if anyone can tell me the steps I need to follow for using the push notification API. or if you have a sample/tutorial.
Thanks

Comment: you should let other know what have you done and where you have got problem .so first let other know your code without it its difficult to help

Comment: Have you read https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime yet?

Comment: thanks for the comments, yes I have read the documentations, I have set the consumer Push API Notifications to push checkins of the users and I have set a https push url(push.php). I dont know the code I should write in the push.php to get the push notifications.

Comment: @Oayam did you get the code working? if so please put the code. im trying to develop something like this to my social app. and have no idea of how to start and work it.

Comment: @Loshi I haven't solved it yet. I was away from that project for a while. If you have found the solution please tell me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Foursquare sends a push to your push.php file, it sends all the data of a checkin. This is what a checking object looks like https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/checkin what you do with that data is up to you.

You could save it to a database; here is an example of taking the checkin object and saving it to a MySQL database: https://github.com/brneese/foursquare-realtime-api-example/blob/master/checkins.php

You can also trigger an event on your server similar to how this pretty smart guy uses it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlGH-uv3kts

Finally you can reply to the checkin using Foursquare's newer function "Reply" part of foursquare's new Apps Platform, currently in developer preview : https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/reply
With "Reply" you could, for instance, send a reminder of the specials you have for your restaurant.

Hope the links and my answer helps.